# NuxtLabs UI: How to set the color of the notification progress bar to something like "bg-red-100"?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

This Question is for the Nuxt package nuxtlabs UI (@nuxthq/ui) (https://ui.nuxtlabs.com/overlays/notification)

How can I change the color of the notification progress bar to something like "bg-red-100" ?
I was reading the documentation, but could not figure out how or if that is possible.

The lines below only change the color to red, but not to "bg-red-100".

```js
const toast = useToast();
    toast.add({
      id: 'update_downloaded',
      title: 'Update downloaded.',
      description: 'It will be installed on restart. Restart now?',      
      color: 'red',   
      progress: {        
        background: 'bg-red-100 dark:bg-red-100',
      },
      timeout: 200000,     
    });
```

Thanks a lot for any help?

Stackbilitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxtlabs-ui-fauvay?file=app.vue